# How to move console cursor up?

Tags: c#, .net, console

I don't want to use `Console.SetCursorPosition`. It has to be seen simple. my purpose is to write some numbers in reverse( from bottom to top) like:

```
                       ...
                      4 5 6
                      1 2 3
```

I cant create an arrow and reverse it either. Is there anything like `\n` or `\b` to do this?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("4 5 6"); Console.WriteLine("1 2 3");`

Comment: @jonesy no, it will write from bottom to top.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have three main options:

- Write the numbers out in reverse. ie: `Console.WriteLine("4 5 6"); Console.WriteLine("1 2 3");`
- Use `Console.SetCursorPosition` (which you mentioned you didn't want to do).
- Make a custom control or other mechanism to display the data, which will write the data as you desire.

The `Console` class does not provide any type of "reverse line feed" operation, other than manually controlling the cursor position.  There is no "backwards \n" you can use.

Comment: It's not possible I guess. I dont know numbers at the first line to write. It ll be calculated from bottom. i.e. lets say calculation is finding prime numbers between an interval.

Comment: perform your calculations before you start writing them out

Comment: @emmett You can perf. the calculations, store them in a `List<string>` as you go, then write them out in reverse order, for example...

Comment: as I said in the question, I can but I cant:) we can reset cursor position to 0,0 in each lines and add new lines but still setcursorposition involved.

Comment: @emmett There is no way to do that in the console, other than setting the cursor position - so you need to rethink your approach.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. But I dont understand why the question was voted down . Was it invalid one ?:)

Comment: @emmett I suspect it was your specific mention of not wanting to use the one method that actually works ;) [I didn't down vote it, though, so I don't know for sure]

Answer (score 12):

This line will move the cursor up one position:

```
Console.CursorTop--;
```