# I have to get the input from the user to moveup or movedown the question in c# console

Tags: c#, .net

```
    class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                IList<Questionnaire> Qs = new List<Questionnaire>()
                {
                new Questionnaire()
                    {
                        questionid = 1,
                        Topic = " Information Technology",
                        Question = "1)what is the important aspects of IT?"
                    },
                new Questionnaire()
                    {
                        questionid = 2,
                        Topic = " Security and compliance",
                        Question = "2)What are security controls?"
                    },
                new Questionnaire()
                    {
                        questionid = 3,
                        Topic = "Risk Assessments",
                        Question = "3)What is Risk Assessent?",
                    },
                new Questionnaire()
                    {
                        questionid = 4,
                        Topic = "Third Party Control",
                        Question = "4)What are third party tools in software?",
                    },
                new Questionnaire()
                    {
                        questionid = 5,
                        Topic = "cloud based solution",
                        Question = "5)What are cloud based solutions?",
                    }
                };
                var questionorderby = Qs.OrderBy(order => order.questionid);
                foreach (var order in questionorderby)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\n" + order.Question);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            public class Questionnaire
            {
                public int? questionid { get; set; }
                public string? Topic { get; set; }
                public string? Question { get; set; }
            }
        }
```

[image: output i get]

output i want:

```
2)What are security controls?
1)what is the important aspects of IT?
3)What is Risk Assessent?
5)What are cloud based solutions?
4)What are third party tools in software?
```

I Want to change the question position using + and - in console using readline. If I click + the question position has to move upwards and - it has to move downward position for eg-> If i click + the 2nd question has to move up and and it has to be in 1st position. If i click - 5th question has to move to the 1st position. I have tried with switch case but i couldn't get it.

```
Console.Write("Enter symbol(+,-):");
string? symbol = Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: The output you get is simple text - why do you post an image of simple text?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to move console cursor up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19596132/how-to-move-console-cursor-up)

Comment: no it doesn't @JohnnyMopp

Comment: It would help a lot if you [explained why you think you need to do this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/). Console applications are not suitable for moving things around on screen. There are also many questionnaire-type apps available on the web, why not use one of those?

Comment: @DourHighArch its my test

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Display Order field to your Questionnaire class and

```
 public class Questionnaire
 {
     public int? Questionid { get; set; }
     public string? Topic { get; set; }
     public string? Question { get; set; }
     public int? DisplayOrder { get; set; }
 }
```

use it to list your questions. So, this can set a new value on input to
index element's DisplayOrder field and update your list.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? @tahananeci